# Best way of showing subwebs in a list

Tags: office-365

We have a root projects site, then we are planning to create a seperate project site for each project becaue of different permissions on each site.

Each project site will consist of few documents and **just 1 list item**, which will have information about the project, for example 21 custom columns.

Now I want to display a list of all projects on project root site with there statuses, **status is in project site list column** what is the best approach for this ?

this is office 365

as each project site will have only 1 list item, can i not just create a root site with a list of projects with 20 columns and give list item permission level to them ?

CN

Comment: Better create folder level permissions.Add a folder in the list and library for each project in the root site. Break inheritance at folder level and assign permissions.This way you can avoid working with different sub sites.

Comment: hi unnie, thank you, can you give me example, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In root site create a List which will store the Project information(lets call it "Project Information").Create a Library which will store the project documents(lets call it "Project Documents").Since Project Information list will have only 1 item per project you can do 2 approaches to display this data to only project members.

1. Item level permission- Create item level permission .You can do this manually through UI or you can use SharePoint 2010 designer workflow impersonation step(This will work even for SP2013, just select SP 2010 workflow platform while creating designer workflow).See this Blog
   [Replace item permissions using designer](http://captainofsharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/how-to-configure-item-level-permissions-during-approval-via-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)
2. Do not create item level permission, add a column project members which contains the project members (multi users) or the project SPGroup, filter the items in the view such that user can see only those items in which Project members=[Me] or user is present in the project members group of that item.
3. Create a workflow which will be activated when item is added to Project Information list, which will create a folder with Project Name in Project Documents library and replace permissions.
   Here is link to a blog to [create folder in library](http://mylittlesharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/05/create-folders-using-spd-workflow.html) through designer workflow.

Step 3 can also be done manually if you wish instead of automating through workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Create Site Columns and Site COntent type for the list item that goes in each sub site.

In the root site, use a Content Search Web part to show all items in the site collection that have that content type. Search will automatically security-trimmed the items, so each user will only see the item(s) for which they have permission.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Content Search WebPart

Answer (score 0):

The one-item list seems like a hacky approach. Here's how I would do it:

Create a custom content type with your project-level metadata. Make it a child of the Web Part Page content type. Add that content type to your SitePages library and set your home pages to that content type.  Then you can add a CQWP to the root site and set it to look for your custom "Project Home Page" content type.  In your CQWP you can group by status or display your data any way you wish.

There are a couple of advantages to this approach: You eliminate the need for a one-item list, and you can also leverage your custom content type in a Search scenario if you so choose.